# prepareForSegue can't get the destination view controller on iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have to write an iOS app that supports both iOS 7 and 8 and in this app I have two view controllers A and B with navigation controllers and a segue between them. When the segue activates, I have to fetch data from the view controller A to the view controller B. My code works perfectly on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == userDataSegue {
        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController

        if let userDataTableViewController = navController?.topViewController as? UserDataTableViewController {
            userDataTableViewController.userData = user
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know why does this happen and how can I fix it? I could "work around" the problem by saving stuff in NSUserDefaults and reading it in the vc B but that would make my code a mess.

I appreciate any help :D

Comment: what's `userDataSegue`?

Comment: what kind of segue is this? a modal one? cause if it is a "regular" push segue the destinationviewcontroller should be the userdatatableviewcontroller and not another navigationcontroller. what is strange is that you say it works on ios8...

Comment: @AndreSlotta the other view controller is a regular view controller with a navigation controller embed in. It's true that it works on iOS 8.

Comment: @rodrigoalves but what kind of segue is it? modal? push?

Comment: @AndreSlotta a push segue

Comment: Ok. In that case you should segue to the userDataTableViewController directly and not to the NavigationController it is embedded in...

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to create a public property userData in Second ViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) 
{
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;

svc.userData = user

}
}
```